# Redis crash when doing pub sub

Tags: multithreading, redis, bukkit

When I'm executing the function `getResource` from jedis, it crashes with following issue:

> [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: Current Thread: Server thread
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:   PID: 18 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: WAITING
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:   Thread is waiting on monitor(s):
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       Locked on:org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:499)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:   Stack:
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:583)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:442)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       pl.imoobler.sectors.managers.RedisManager.updatePosition(RedisManager.java:44)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       pl.imoobler.sectors.utils.BungeeUtils.teleportServer(BungeeUtils.java:28)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       pl.imoobler.sectors.listeners.PlayerMoveListener.detectSectorSwap(PlayerMoveListener.java:88)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor6.execute(Unknown Source)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor$1.execute(EventExecutor.java:44)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:78)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:514)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:499)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:649)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInFlying.a(SourceFile:126)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInFlying$PacketPlayInPosition.a(SourceFile:57)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$ensureMainThread$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:14)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$$Lambda$199/2109184961.run(Unknown Source)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:46)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:842)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:423)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:766)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:664)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [17:04:58] [Paper Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: ------------------------------

My code:

```
package pl.imoobler.sectors.managers;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import pl.imoobler.sectors.SectorsPlugin;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException;

import java.util.UUID;

public class RedisManager {

SectorsPlugin plugin;
JedisPool pool;
Gson gson = new Gson();

public RedisManager(SectorsPlugin plugin, String redisHost) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    pool = new JedisPool(redisHost);
}

public void subscribe(final JedisPubSub pubSub, final String... channels) {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(plugin, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
            try {
                jedis.select(0);
                jedis.subscribe(pubSub, channels);
            } catch (JedisConnectionException ex) {
                pool.returnBrokenResource(jedis);
            } finally {
                pool.returnResource(jedis);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void updatePosition(UUID uuid, String position, String target) {
    Jedis subscriber = null;
    try {
        subscriber = pool.getResource();
        subscriber.set(("sectors:" + "positions" + ":" + uuid.toString()), position);
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.addProperty("position_player_uuid", uuid.toString());
        object.addProperty("position_player_target", target);
        subscriber.publish("NewPlayerLocationChannel", gson.toJson(object));
    }catch(JedisConnectionException ex) {
        pool.returnBrokenResource(subscriber);
    } finally {
        pool.returnResource(subscriber);
    }
}

public String getPosition(UUID uuid) {
    Jedis subscriber = pool.getResource();
    if(subscriber.exists(("sectors:" + "positions" + ":" + uuid.toString()))) {
        return subscriber.get(("sectors:" + "positions" + ":" + uuid.toString()));
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you reached your JedisPool size? The default JedisPool size is really small.